# Why does an SFTP connection still exist after the JSCH Channel has been closed?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

When the code below has finished running, `netstat -a|grep sftp` shows an open SFTP connection. It also shows up as an open connection in JProfiler.

`channel.isConnected()` in the *finally* block prints *false*. Any ideas why the connections is not being closed as I'm at a loss?

```
public static void clean() {
    com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp channel = null;
    try {
        channel = Helper.openNewTLSftpChannel();
        channel.connect();
        channel.cd(remoteFileDirectory);

        List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = channel.ls("*." + fileType);
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : list) {
            String fileName = file.getFilename();
            DateTime fileDate = new DateTime(parseDateFromFileName(fileName));

            //if this file is older than the cutoff date, delete from the SFTP share
            if (fileDate.compareTo(cleanupCutoffdate) < 0) {
                channel.rm(fileName);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
            System.out.println(channel.isConnected());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Adding `openNewTLSftpChannel()` below:

```
public static ChannelSftp openNewSftpChannel(String privateKeyFileName, String password, String username, String host, int port)
        throws ConfigurationErrorException {

    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    File sftpPrivateFile = new File(privateKeyFileName);
    Channel channel;
    try {
        if (!sftpPrivateFile.canRead()) {
            throw new ConfigurationErrorException("File access error: " + sftpPrivateFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        jsch.addIdentity(sftpPrivateFile.getAbsolutePath(), password);
        Session session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    } catch (JSchException jschException) {
        throw new ConfigurationErrorException("File access error: " + sftpPrivateFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return (ChannelSftp) channel;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you take a look at the JSCH [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) for SFTP you'll see how the session is terminated:

```
//setup Session here 
...
session.connect();
...


Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;

...run sftp logic...

//close sessions here
sftpChannel.exit();
session.disconnect();
```

You'll notice that there are two parts to the connection and disconnection; the Session object and the Channel object.

In my code I use the Session object to set my authentication information, and the Channel object to execute the sftp commands I need.

In your instance, you're creating the Session object in your openNewSftpChannel method, but it is never closed, hence your session stays alive.

For further context, check out the examples.

Comment: One can have multiple channels inside of one session (both at the same time as well as sequentially), therefore it is a good thing that the session is not auto-closed when one channel is closed.

Comment: This is not true -- exit just calls disconnect. Nothing else.

Comment: sftpChannel.exit() calls the disconnect method via the Channel class, which ChannelSftp inherits (line 494 of Channel.java), session.disconnect is invoked via its own disconnect method (line 1545 of Session.java).

Comment: @RobertH Does disconnecting a sftp session terminates / exits all open channels too?

Comment: @Ayrush To be honest it's been quite a wile since I've used JSCH so I am not up to date on the library, that said if I recall correctly disconnect only worked on the session object created and would have no effect on other open channels

Comment: Session.disconnect() calls Channel.disconnect(session object) which goes over the channels in the pool of channels and calls channels[i].disconnect(), synchronized on the pool. Ver. 0.1.55.

Answer (score 9):

Robert H is correct, you need to exit your channel and disconnect your session.  I wanted to add that the session exists even when the channel has been closed.  Since you create your session within a try block inside a method, it seems you have lost your session, but you can get it back using 'getSession' on your sftpChannel channel.

You can change your finally block to this:

```
} finally {
    if (channel != null) {
        Session session = channel.getSession();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println(channel.isConnected());
    }
}
```

Comment: Invoking session.disconnect(); is sufficient, as it will trigger the disconnect() method on all channels within the current session.